# Placing objects to other object in ARCore Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore

I need help with placing models. What my app does:
Firstly, a user places the sphere, then on the sphere can be placed other object at an angle. something like in picture 1.
[picture 1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJEv1.png

A had an idea to place anchor with a rise using
`session!!.createAnchor(Pose.makeTranslation(0f, 0.5f, 0f).compose(hit.hitPose))`
however it doesn't work by Y coordinate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work by Y coordinate"? Do you get an error, or is there some other issue? Being specific helps us help you.

Comment: @ShaneBishop , I mean that there is no shift along the Y-axis, only along X or Z Pose.makeTranslation(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f).